# My request for a second view it doesn't show anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, vue.js, axios

I'm using ruby on rails as framework and vue.js to display de data and for the request to the API I'm using axios.

first I create  project with:

```
rails new myapp --webpack=vue
```

that created one folder in rails:

```
app/javascript
└── packs
    ├── app.vue
    └── hello_vue.js
```

app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul v-for="result in results">
      <li>{{result.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- <p>{{ results.name}}</p> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    results: []
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get("xxxxx")
    .then(response => {
      this.results = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

hello_vue.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hello'))
  const app = new Vue(App).$mount('hello')

  console.log(app)
})
```

that allow me to insert the information in the views like:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %>
```

and works it show the information.

But when I try to make a new folder with new files like this :

```
app/javascript
    └── datos
        ├── app2.vue
        └── hello2_vue.js
```

app2:

```
<template>
  <div id="app2">
    <ul v-for="result in results">
      <li>{{result.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: {
    results: []
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .then(response => {
      this.results = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

hello2:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App2 from './app2.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hello2'))
  const app2 = new Vue(App2).$mount('hello2')

  console.log(app2)
})
```

and them load the files:

```
<%= javascript_datos_tag 'hello2_vue' %>
```

it show this error:

```
undefined method `javascript_datos_tag' for #<#<Class:0x0055a86f9b0218>:0x007fd3cf6d9958>
Did you mean?  javascript_cdata_section
               javascript_tag
               javascript_pack_tag
```

Comment: `javascript_datos_tag`, why would you use that? I haven't ever heard of it before. the `javascript_pack_tag` isn't 'dynamic' from the packs-folder-name.

Comment: I try to include new files in the packs folder but it doesn't work only work if I make a copy of those files example: app2 and hello2_vue

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that guy I just check my server foreman and apparently it needs to be re-start every time I add new views ans requests, in the foreman server like.

```
$foreman start
```